# Filter a multi-dimensional [3 dimensions] array in js

Tags: javascript, filter

Given the following array in JavaScript:

```
_articles = [{ id: 0, name: 'aaa', categories: [1,2,3], date: '2021-05-17'}, { id: 1, name: 'bbb', categories: [7,22,6], date: '2021-03-15'}, { id: 0, name: 'ccc', categories: [11], date: '2021-02-11'}, { id: 0, name: 'ddd', categories: [2,22,1], date: '2021-04-11'}]
```

How can be **filtered by category that contains a value = 2**?

```
_articles_output = [{ id: 0, name: 'aaa', categories: [1,2,3], date: '2021-05-17'},{ id: 0, name: 'ddd', categories: [2,22,1], date: '2021-04-11'}]
```

The first code I tried with c_id == 2 (it is not working):

```
_articles = _articles.filter(({ category_id }) => c_id in category_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to achieve the desired result.

```js
_articles = [
  { id: 0, name: "aaa", categories: [1, 2, 3], date: "2021-05-17" },
  { id: 1, name: "bbb", categories: [7, 22, 6], date: "2021-03-15" },
  { id: 0, name: "ccc", categories: [11], date: "2021-02-11" },
  { id: 0, name: "ddd", categories: [2, 22, 1], date: "2021-04-11" },
];

const _articles_output = _articles.filter((o) => o.categories.includes(2));
console.log(_articles_output);
```